# Cyclocross suspension

Tags: suspension, cyclocross

I would like to know if there is any brand that sells cyclocross bikes with front suspension. I would like to buy the Specialized Crux E5 but I also like the Trek DS 4 but this one is flat and I want it from road.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "I want it from road"? Do you mean that you want to use the bike _on_ the road? If so, suspension really isn't necessary unless you're riding on rather rough roads. Also, could you explain why you're mentioning these specific bikes? It's not clear how they tie in to your question -- do you want something kind of like a Crux E5 with suspension like the DS 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While proper cyclocross bikes typically do not have front suspension, you can find a few drop-bar bikes that do have it.  The Cannondale Slate is one: http://www.cannondale.com/en/USA/Bike/ProductDetail?Id=4a8a930f-c1de-422f-bf23-81d13da8c706

These bikes are usually called "adventure bikes."  While most adventure bikes still don't have suspension, the term may help you narrow your search.

You may find that a good quality, wide front tire is enough suspension.  Any drop-bar bike with clearance for tires at least 40mm wide should be useful here.  This opens your options up to a much bigger slice of the adventure bike market.